# Signup Form Values not passing from Client side to Server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

My signup form data is not getting passed to backend. Mainly, I got problem while using `bcrypt.hash()` function which is getting the `password` value as `undefined`. But in `frontend`, whenever I click `submit button`, I get values of the `form` in `console`. I'm in trouble to find out the exact problem  and fix the issue. Please anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Here is my `frontend` point from where I'm requesting to `backend`.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie'
import axios from 'axios'
import SigninImage from '../assets/signup.jpg'

const cookies = new Cookies()

const initialState = {
    fullName: '',
    username: '',
    Password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    avatarURL: ''
}

const Auth = () => {
    const [form, setForm] = useState(initialState)
    const [isSignup, setIsSignup] = useState(true)

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setForm({ ...form, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        const { username, password, phoneNumber, avatarURL } = form

        const URL = 'http://localhost:5000/auth'

        const { data: { token, userId, hashedPassword, fullName } } = await axios.post(`${URL}/${isSignup ? 'signup' : 'login'}`, {
            username, password, fullName: form.fullName, phoneNumber, avatarURL,
        })
        
        cookies.set('token', token)
        cookies.set('username', username)
        cookies.set('fullName', fullName)
        cookies.set('userId', userId)

        if (isSignup) {
            cookies.set('phoneNumber', phoneNumber)
            cookies.set('avatarURL', avatarURL)
            cookies.set('hashedPassword', hashedPassword)
        }

        window.location.reload()
    }

    const switchMode = () => {
        setIsSignup((prevState) => !prevState)
    }

    return (
        <div className='auth__form-container'>
            <div className='auth__form-container_fields'>
                <div className='auth__form-container_fields-content'>
                    <p>{isSignup ? 'Sign Up' : 'Sign In'}</p>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        {isSignup && (
                            <div className='auth__form-container_fields-content_input'>
                                <label htmlFor="fullName">Full Name</label>
                                <input
                                    name='fullName'
                                    type='text'
                                    placeholder='Full Name'
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                        )}

                        <div className='auth__form-container_fields-content_input'>
                            <label htmlFor="username">UserName</label>
                            <input
                                name='username'
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='User Name'
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                required
                            />
                        </div>

                        {isSignup && (
                            <div className='auth__form-container_fields-content_input'>
                                <label htmlFor="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                                <input
                                    name='phoneNumber'
                                    type='text'
                                    placeholder='Phone Number'
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                        )}

                        {isSignup && (
                            <div className='auth__form-container_fields-content_input'>
                                <label htmlFor="avatarURL">Avatar URL</label>
                                <input
                                    name='avatarURL'
                                    type='text'
                                    placeholder='Avatar URL'
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                        )}

                        <div className='auth__form-container_fields-content_input'>
                            <label htmlFor="Password">Password</label>
                            <input
                                name='Password'
                                type='password'
                                placeholder='Password'
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                required
                            />
                        </div>

                        {isSignup && (
                            <div className='auth__form-container_fields-content_input'>
                                <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                                <input
                                    name='confirmPassword'
                                    type='password'
                                    placeholder='Confirm Password'
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                        )}

                        <div className='auth__form-container_fields-content_button'>
                            <button type='submit'>{isSignup ? 'Sign Up' : "Sign In"}</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div className='auth__form-container_fields-account'>
                        <p>
                            {isSignup ? 'Already have an account? ' : "Don't have account? "}
                            <span onClick={switchMode}>
                                {isSignup ? "Sign In" : "Sign up"}
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="auth__form-container_image">
                <img src={SigninImage} alt="sign in" />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Auth
```

And the `backend` point where I'm receiving the request.

```
const { connect } = require('getstream')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const { StreamChat } = require('stream-chat').StreamChat

require('dotenv').config()

const api_key = process.env.STREAM_API_KEY
const api_secret = process.env.STREAM_API_SECRET
const app_id = process.env.STREAM_APP_ID

const signup = async (req, res) => { 
    try {
        const { fullName, username, password, phoneNumber } = req.body

        const userId = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex')

        const serverClient = connect(api_key, api_secret, app_id)
        
        console.log(password) //getting undefined
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)

        const token = serverClient.createUserToken(userId)

        res.status(200).json({token, userId, username, hashedPassword, phoneNumber, fullName})
    
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

        res.status(500).json({message: error})
    }
}


const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body

        const serverClient = connect(api_key, api_secret, app_id)

        const client = StreamChat.getInstance(api_key, api_secret)

        const { users } = await client.queryUsers({ name: username })
        
        if (!users.length) return res.status(400).json({ message: "User not found!" })
        
        const success = await bcrypt.compare(password, users[0].hashedPassword)

        const token = serverClient.createUserToken(users[0].id)

        if (success) {
            res.status(200).json({token, fullName:users[0].fullName, username, userId:users[0].id})
        } else {
            res.status(500).json({message: "Incorrect Password."})
        }
    } catch (error) {
        
    }
 }

module.exports = {login, signup}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more details re this?

- What do you get when you `console.log(req.body)`?
- Check your browser network tab, is there data in the payload?

Try the following:

- Everything looks good except, you're missing this two middleware in your backend. Include them and let's see

```
// Middlewares
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply brother. I checked ```console.log(req.body)``` and except ```password``` field, I got all other fields. I used both of the middlewares you mentioned above in my ```index.js``` file. My network tab is showing ```status code 200``` but as the request cannot be completed, it's returning ```500```.

Comment: Oopps! I made a foolish mistake. It was ```Password``` and ```password``` issue. I misspelled this, it was a ```case sensitivity``` issue.

Comment: Awesome, happy you're able to solve your bug.